# Problems with material preview, wireframe and rendered modes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, gpu

Viewport shading (material preview) is not working, and Viewport shading (wireframe) works only in edit mode, in object mode does not work, but should work in both. Viewport shading (rendered) also does not work, it fixes by switching from eevee to cycles. The blender has been reinstalled several times, the video card driver too, and Windows has reinstalled a bunch of times. Please help solve the problem!

P.S. Video with glitches is available on Google Drive at the link below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VsWSRUYS8oDy8Qbej4yfqoT951KGI_Gh/view?usp=sharing

[image: solid mode]

[image: Material preview]

[image: rendered mode (eevee)]

[image: rendered mode (cycles)]

[image: wireframe in edit mode]

[image: wireframe in object mode]

Comment: Long and the short of it is that the latest AMD Adrenalin drivers cause this issue. Roll back to an earlier driver version, or enable "High Quality Normals" in the render properties panel.